# How to extract nested data from BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I have a table in Google Cloud Platform using BigQuery with nested data and I want to extract these data in single rows.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCcDP.png)

| Row | title_localized.text | title_localized.language | title_localized.truncated | publication_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Revêtements en polyuréthane bicomposants stables | fr | false | 20210107 |
|  | Beständige 2k-pur-beschichtungen | de | false |  |
|  | Resistant 2k-pur coatings | en | false |  |
| 2 | Revêtements en polyuréthane bicomposants stables | fr | false | 20210507 |
|  | Resistant 2k-pur coatings | en | false |  |
|  | Beständige 2k-pur-beschichtungen | de | false |  |

and i want to turn this table in unnested form.

| Row | title_localized.text | title_localized.language | title_localized.truncated | publication_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Revêtements en polyuréthane bicomposants stables | fr | false | 20210107 |
| 2 | Beständige 2k-pur-beschichtungen | de | false | 20210107 |
| 3 | Resistant 2k-pur coatings | en | false | 20210107 |
| 4 | Revêtements en polyuréthane bicomposants stables | fr | false | 20210507 |
| 5 | Resistant 2k-pur coatings | en | false | 20210507 |
| 6 | Beständige 2k-pur-beschichtungen | de | false | 20210507 |

Tried this but won't work:

```
SELECT
    title_localized,
    publication_date
FROM
    `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
    UNNEST(title_localized) as test
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, its just that you are including the array field in the query output as well.

This query excludes the unnested array field:

```
SELECT
  test.text,
  test.language,
  test.truncated
  
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
  UNNEST(title_localized) as test
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select publication_number, local_title.*, publication_date
from `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
unnest(title_localized) local_title
```

with output like below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes i have tried. It worked! Thanks a lot!